# How to create an image of a velocity field representing Kolmogorov structure function?

Tags: simulations, turbulence

I want to create a two-dimensional image where each pixel represents a velocity. The velocities are distributed in such a way that if you plot a function of separation between all unique pairs of pixels ($l$) vs the absolute difference between the velocities of those pixels ($|dv|$), the slope of the relation is 1/3 in log space, i.e. $|dv|$ is proportional to $l^{1/3}$. A graph like that is called the velocity structure function and for inertial Kolmogorov turbulence, the slope of the relation between $dv$ and $l$ in log space is 1/3.

I found a Python code ([see this](https://github.com/cphyc/FyeldGenerator)) that generates a Gaussian random field with a power spectrum of any given power law index $P(k) \propto k^{-n}$. Does the image generated using that method represent the Kolmogorov structure function if I choose $n=-1$?